# Override parent Docker arguments

Tags: docker, dockerfile, arguments

Let the parent Docker some_img have argument `X` set to `'0'`.

How to override the argument value and have the parent Docker use other X?

I tried

```
ARG X='1'
FROM some_img:latest

...do stuff...
```

but clearly some_img still uses `X='0'` because `ARG='0'` is specified in some_img Dockerfile. ENV would take precedence over ARG, but this is not allowed before FROM.

Note that if I were just to build some_img, I could override ARG in Dockerfile by using `--build-arg` option in `docker build`.

Is there any way to override arguments in parent Docker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this.

The result of `docker build` is an opaque, immutable image.  A downstream Dockerfile's `FROM` line doesn't rebuild the image, it simply imports that opaque image as-is.  You can't change what's in the image or its build options after it's been built, or cause it to be rebuilt in the later Dockerfile.

If you control both images, it's possible the thing you're trying to change shouldn't be a build-time `ARG` at all.  Things like upstream package version numbers can be good `ARG`s (a Java 8 vs. Java 11 version of something is likely "different" enough to merit two builds but still be quite similar on the whole; updating from version 3.4.1 to 3.4.2 of some library probably only involves changing a version number but not any logic).  Things where you need to control the behavior later on (numeric user IDs, database locations, ...) should be configured some other way and not built in to an image.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. I realized I have to rebuild the parent image with the arguments I need and then use this new image as an actual base in FROM. An extra step but it works.